# Deleting an object of a nested data in Angular using NGXS

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, ngxs, angular-state-managmement

I have successfully implemented the get and delete function of post in my Angular app. My problem comes when you wanted to delete a comment inside a post. I'm trying to achieve it using NGXS. How will i be able to access it inside of the post so i can retrieve the comment to be able to delete it.
Here's what i have done

[SEE THIS LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-delete-nested-object)

> CODE

```
onDeleteComment(id: number){
    this.store.dispatch(new DeleteComment(id));
}



 @Action(DeleteComment)
  deleteComment(
    { getState, setState }: StateContext<PostStateModel>,
    { id }: DeleteComment
  ) {
    const state = getState();
    const filteredArray = state.posts.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    setState({
      ...state,
      posts: filteredArray
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to delete the comment from a post you'd have to *first* specify from which post you'd like to remove the comment:

```
// app.component.ts
onDeleteComment(postId: number, commentId: number){
  this.store.dispatch(new DeleteComment(postId, commentId));
}
```

*Next step* is to update your `DeleteComment` action to accept new parameter:

```
// post.action.ts
constructor(public readonly postId: number, public readonly commentId: number) { }
```

And *lastly*, update your state with the help of ngxs's [state operators](https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/operators) (`patch`, `updateItem`, `removeItem`):

```
@Action(DeleteComment)
deleteComment(
  { getState, setState }: StateContext<PostStateModel>,
  { postId, commentId }: DeleteComment
) {
  const state = getState();

  setState(patch<PostStateModel>({
    // firstly, you're modifying the post by removing a comment from it
    posts: updateItem<Post>(p => p.id === postId, patch<Post>({
      // secondly, you remove the comment itself
      comments: removeItem<Comment>(c => c.id === commentId)
    }))
  }));
}
```

Here is a link to [updated stackblitz](https://ngxs-delete-nested-object-8fs3x2.stackblitz.io)